# Unit test that checks Web API 2 Controller takes forever to Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, nunit

EDIT: I've added `async`/`await` keywords to no avail.

When running the following unit test,

```
private const string jsonRequest = @"
[
  {
    ""productId"": ""279"",
    ""price"": ""20.00"",
  }
]";

[TestMethod]
public async Task GivenAPostedJsonPayload_ThenCheckIfDataIsBeingSavedOnDatabase()
{
    var controller = new MyBelovedController();
    var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest);
    message.Content = content;
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    controller.Request = message;

    var response = await controller.PostIncrementalChange();
}
```

with the following `MyBelovedController`,

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostIncrementalChange()
{
    string jsonRequest = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Debugger gets stuck here.

    /* JSON deserialization and database processing take place here. */

    return Ok();
}
```

the debugger gets stuck at the aforementioned line and takes forever to step to the next line.

Question: is there any way to make it run faster?

Specs:

- My Visual Studio 2019 Professional build version is 16.8.5.
- Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.04084.
- Microsoft Windows 10 Version 2004 build version 19041.867.

EDIT: my laptop is hitting 100% CPU usage while I debug the solution, might it be the cause?

[image: Task Manager Performance indicators]

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way to use async pattern. Mark your methods as async and return `Task`. Await the async call. Remove `.Result` so it is non-blocking.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GivenAPostedJsonPayload_ThenCheckIfDataIsBeingSavedOnDatabase()
{
    blah, blah, blah...

    var response = await controller.PostIncrementalChange();

    Assert.AreEqual(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task PostIncrementalChange()
{
    string jsonRequest = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hey @Crowcoder, thank you for your reply! Do you think the controller would break if I added `async` and tried POSTing with Postman?

Comment: No, it would not break.

Comment: I've added the `async`/`await` keywords to no avail.

Comment: You haven't shown your updates. You can edit your question. Also important could be what is the "etc." code that you have omitted. Deadlocks can happen deep in call stacks so that is why you must use async "all the way down".

Comment: The updates to the question are shown above. The `etc.` has been removed. I explained that there is a JSON deserialization and processing steps there. Thank you!

Comment: Your test method should be `async Task`, not `async void`

Comment: You may not have a deadlock, but like I said, it can happen anywhere in the call stack so check everything called by this code and everything it calls, etc. You can also try this hack - append `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your async method calls.